# onchange on widget oracle right now

Tags: javascript, rightnow-crm

I have a FormInput widget with selection sub_id :

```
<rn:widget path="input/FormInput" name="Incident.CustomFields.c.customer_type"label_input="#rn:msg:CUSTOM_MSG_CUSTOMER_TYPE_LBL#" class="form-control" id="cstype" sub_id="selection" onchange="StoreSectors();"/>
```

And in javascript I have only this :

```js
function StoreSectors() {
  alert('Its Working');
}
```

but onchange it's not working this way . How can I grab the onchange event of a selection input with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add an event listener OR use jQuery in the bottom of the page after load. Usually custom fields have different id prefixes but have the custom field name ending:

Example:

`$("[id$='CustomFields.c.customer_type']").change(function(){
    StoreSectors();
});`